# retrieving empty record from informationschema. WHY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
```

Above SQL is not showing any data while 20minutes ago it was showing all the records, just fine! How is that even possible?

Comment: Are you looking at the right database? Are you sure you didn't drop all constraints?

Comment: @Oded - You typed that while I was posting it as an answer... Truly, I did not mean to steal your idea.  If you want to post that as an answer, I'll delete mine since you really beat me to it.

Comment: @David - Don't be silly.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running it against the right database?

When I run the query against my Master dtatabase, I get no results, but when I run it against a different DB I get results.

If you're using Sql Server Management Studio, put a `USE <database name that you want to run this against>` statement before this query.

For example, if the DB name is "sales" then put

```
USE SALES
GO
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
```